# Finding all elements that have the value zero in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have performed a quantization on pixels after finding the dct values of the pixels. Now my task is to find all elements that equal zero in the resulting numpy array.
The np.non_zero() function returns all the indices, that is not exactly what I want. How can I go about doing this.
At first I thought I could just iterate over the numpy array but it would take forever for (400,400) array.

For example, I have the following np array:

```
    [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
     [ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
     [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
     [24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]
     [32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
     [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47]
     [48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55]
     [56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63]]
```

There is one zero in that. I'd like to know how to get that zero and any other zeroes that may exist.

Comment: like `a == 0` ?

Comment: Nevermind, I used the length if non-zero indices and obtained the difference. For now that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

not an expert of `numpy` but I hope this could help:

```
In [135]: a = np.random.randint(5, size=(30,30))
In [136]: i = 0
In [137]: j = 0
In [138]: for x in a.tolist():
    for y in x:
        if ( y == 0 ):
            print i,j
        j += 1
    i += 1
    j = 0
   .....:     
0 4
0 8
0 10
0 25
...

In [139]: a[0][25]
Out[139]: 0

In [140]: a[0][4]
Out[140]: 0

In [141]: a[0][8]
Out[141]: 0

In [142]: a[0][9]
Out[142]: 1
```

Thanks